# Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Stream Binder, MessageChannel is not created

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I have a problem in my simple test application. I'd like create consumer with kafka stream binder like [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/3.1.0/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_functional_style).

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CloudStreamAggregatorApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(CloudStreamAggregatorApplication.class, args);
  }
  @Bean
  public Consumer<KStream<String,String>> consume() {
    return input -> input.foreach((k,v) -> System.out.println("CONSUMER: "+v));
  }
}
```

But when i try to test it

```
@SpringBootTest
@EmbeddedKafka
@Import(TestChannelBinderConfiguration.class)
@DirtiesContext
class CloudStreamConsumerApplicationTests {

  @Autowired
  private InputDestination input;

  @Test
  void test01_Consume() {
    input.send(new GenericMessage<>("test"));
  }
}
```

I receive exception

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
  at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64) ~[na:na]
  at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70) ~[na:na]
  at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248) ~[na:na]
  at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:359) ~[na:na]
  at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:427) ~[na:na]
  at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.test.AbstractDestination.getChannel(AbstractDestination.java:34) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.1.0-test-binder.jar:3.1.0]
```

And when i change consume method to

```
@Bean
public Consumer<Flux<String>> consume() {
    return f -> f.subscribe(p -> System.out.println("CONSUMER: "+p));
}
```

It's ok.

I try to print created channels

```
@Autowired
private Map<String,MessageChannel> channels;
...
channels.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.println("CHANNEL: "+k));
```

I receive in first case

```
CHANNEL: nullChannel
CHANNEL: errorChannel
```

And in second case

```
CHANNEL: nullChannel
CHANNEL: errorChannel
CHANNEL: consume-in-0
CHANNEL: test.anonymous.errors
```

I didn't get why it happens. Сan anyone help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Kafka Streams binder is not a `MessageChannelBinder` so it doesn't use message channels internally.

You can't test with the test messsage channel binder.

Comment: Thanks. But what is a correct way to test kafka stream binder?

Comment: Use the real broker with spring-kafka-test's `EmbeddedKafkaBroker` - see the [samples](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/kafka-streams-samples) for examples. More information about the embedded broker [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#testing) and in its Javadocs.

Comment: It seems to me, IndexOutOfBoundsException is not suitable in this case:) for example IllegalStateException will be more understanding.

Comment: I don’t disagree. It is not intuitive. Consider opening an issue on GitHub.